# show each customers' names, how much each person has spent in total, and how many orders they have made

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsgoK.jpg)

I am trying to extract infomation from atable to solve the aforementioned question:

> show each customers' names, how much each person has spent in total, and how many orders they have made

Here is my attempt

```
select firstName, lastName, ISNULL(totalOrders, 0), ISNULL(totalSpent) from Customers as C
join (
    SELECT customerID, count(orderNumber) as totalOrders from CustomerOrders
    ORDER BY COUNT(orderNumber) ASC
) AS CO ON CO.customerID = C.customerID

JOIN (
    select sum(orderNumber) as totalSpent from ItemsInOrder
    order by C.lastName
) as IIO ON IIO.totalSpent = CO.totalOrders
```

Unfortunately, this did not run. Also i'm trying to get my result to be ordered by order count in ascending and order by the customer's last name but I'm having a hard time, as I don't know where to place it.

I feel like this is an easy question but I kept overthinking it and ending up being confused

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) If you want to supply sample data, DDL and DML is best, and for expected results markdown tables work well.

Comment: *"Unfortunately, this did not run."* did you get an error, something else?

Comment: *"as I don't know where to place it."* The `ORDER BY` goes at the *end* of the query.

Comment: it keeps saying errors and though i felt like im missing something i just cant quite figure it out :/

Comment: so is it just the placement of my ORDER BY ?

Comment: There are several errors here, you could have mentioned error messages you get. 1. The `CO` subquery needs a `GROUP BY`. 2. `ORDER BY` In a subquery is not allowed, unless `TOP` is specified. 3. A join on a total count of rows in `ItemsInOrder` and a count of orders for each customer is unlikely to be correct. I think the logic of this query is off, please add table structures, sample data and expected results in the question itself, not as a link to another resource

Answer (score 1):

As @HoneyBadger has pointed out in the comments, you are not using any group by clause, so that is going to error out. But, you have to look at how you join your tables as well. It does not make sense to equate the sum of item costs to the total number of orders. You should be joining that on order number.

Here is a quick and dirty answer using outer apply. Because count ignores nulls in the count on a single column, we don't need an isnull or a coalesce there, but we would on the sum column.

```
select
c.firstname,
c.lastname,
sum(coalesce(c.totalspend, 0)) as TotalSpend,
count(a.orderNumber) as Numorders
from customers c
outer apply
(
    select co.customerid, orderNumber, sum(totalItemCost) as TotalSpend
    from customerorders co
    left join itemsinorders ii on ii.ordernumber = co.ordernumber
    group by co.customerid, ordernumber
) a on a.customerid = c.customerid
Group by c.firstname, c.lastname
```

If outer apply doesn't work, you should be able to do it all with joins with a count(distinct). So,

```
select
c.firstname,
c.lastname,
count(distinct o.ordernumber) as NumOrders,
sum(coalesce(i.totalspend, 0) as totalSpend
from customers c
left join customerorders o on o.customerid = c.customerid
left join itemsinorders i on i.orderid = o.orderid
group by c.firstname, c.lastname
```

Without being able to check on the null values of distinct, this should work and is easier to read.